# Pyside QTablewidget qcheckbox click event

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, qtablewidget, qcheckbox

I have added qcheckbox in first cell of qtablewidget now what I want is how to access checkbox and how to get its click event.Basically what I want is on checkbox check row should be selected and on unchecked row should be dis-selected.
Here is code:

```
def add_items(self):
    rows = 5
    cols = 5
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
    for r in range(0, rows):
        for c in range(1, cols):

            self.qwidget = QtGui.QWidget()
            self.checkbox = QtGui.QCheckBox()
            self.checkbox.setCheckState(QtCore.Qt.Checked)
            qhboxlayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.qwidget)
            qhboxlayout.addWidget(self.checkbox)
            qhboxlayout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
            qhboxlayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
            self.tableWidget.setCellWidget(r, 0, self.qwidget)

            item = QTableWidgetItem('note'+str(r))
            self.tableWidget.setItem(r, c, item)
    print 'done'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`itemChanged`](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtGui/QTableWidget.html?highlight=itemchanged#PySide.QtGui.PySide.QtGui.QTableWidget.itemChanged) signal.

```
from PySide.QtCore import Slot, Qt
from PySide.QtGui import QTableWidgetItem

@Slot(QTableWidgetItem)
def on_tableWidget_itemChanged(self, item):
    """ Handles the row's state
    :type item: QTableWidgetItem
    :parameter item: The changed item
    """
    checked = item.checkState() == Qt.Checked
    if checked:  # the item gets checked
        # do stuff here..
    else:  # the item gets unchecked
        # do stuff here
```